# Editing the width of a CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am trying to edit the width of the cell so that no matter what screen size, I will have `score1.count` cells in a row. The code I am using for my Collection View is the following:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    cell.myLabel.text = String(self.items[indexPath.item])

    return cell
}
```

This is the function targeting the width of the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = Int(self.view.frame.size.width)/(score1.count + 1)
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(size), height: 80)
}
```

I have spent many hours looking at different sources and trying different things, but the collection view never has the right number of cells. One idea is that it may be because I have the cell size set in auto layout but whenever I go to change it xcode crashes. Any ideas on bypassing the auto layout? Or how to change the auto layout?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you setting the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` ?

Comment: No, but I don't reference it in the code.

Comment: changed the UICollectionViewDelegate to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and it worked! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
extension YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let rowItems:CGFloat = 4
    let padding:CGFloat = 2
    let width = (collectionView.bounds.width / rowItems) - padding //Change width as per your requirement
    let height = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * padding)//Change height as per your requirement
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm sure these answers work, but it is still conforming to what I specified in storyboard layout options. How do I override that? Leave it blank? Or is there a line of code I'm missing somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your sizeForItemAtIndexPath as. You can assign size of cell after substracting margin and diving by number of cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = (Int(collectionView.bounds.width) - (score1.count+1)*5) /(score1.count)  // 5 is the margin you want to keep in between 2 cells
        return CGSize(width: CGFloat(size), height: 80)
    }
```

Do let me know if you have any queries. I would try and clarify.

Comment: You have one too many parenthesis after the 5.  It works better but still has one more than the score1.count.

Comment: Yepp my mistake. Actually m away from my system,m acccessing it from mobile. "It works better but still has one more than the score1.count." what does that mean.

Comment: what are you getting

Comment: before I had had 11 cells in a row, when `score1.count` usually is 9. Now I had 10 but that might be because the margin is 5 and it was 0.

Comment: Basically, I want to take the total width of the device, I'm guessing there is something for that. Then divide by score1.count. Is that possible? Also what does this do: `*`

Comment: you can get width of screen as UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width. It would be better if you take collection views frame and then substract margin and divide by cell you want to add i.e. score1.count.

Comment: How can I override the storyboard layout editor? Is that the UICollectionViewFlowLayout. ANd where would that go?

Comment: you need to set your class as delegate of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. Hope it helps!!

Comment: you need to set your class as delegate of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. Hope it helps!!